# How to get data from Indexed DB using Dexie.js so that each time I am add data and I can get back them and show in html page in a list format?

Tags: javascript, html, json, indexeddb, dexie

[Image of saving data into IndexedDB is as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePviF.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have stored data into IndexedDB by using Dexie.js wrapper. They are saved in the IndexedDB as shown above image link. Now I want to fetch the data from IndexedDB and show them in the html page. What is the way to do that?